# SN730 NVME disk broken, disk is read only, SMART errors, can it be fixed?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I use a dual boot Fedora 33 - KDE and Windows 10 on my MSI GL75 Laptop, with a WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-1T disk.
After booting Windows after a long time, I tried resizing my partitions, I only clicked on "resize" in Windows's disks tool, but then canceled because I thought I would do it from Linux the next day. (So Windows was not supposed to write anything to the hard drive)
But this morning when I booted into Linux, it said several times that my system was read only, so I rebooted, again, and this time it got me to an emergency mode, saying that it couldn't read my hard drive.
I booted to a live os key and tried to back up some important data, but when I tried mounting my disk it said I had superblock problems.
I tried to get my drive's health via SMARTctl and this was the output :

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-1T00-1032
Firmware Version:                   11111000
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x15b7
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x001b44
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      8215
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            001b44 8b46bf3bc1
Local Time is:                      Thu Dec 24 18:51:37 2020 CET
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x02):        NA_Fields

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     3.50W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.1000W       -        -    3  3  3  3     4000   10000
 4 -   0.0025W       -        -    4  4  4  4     4000   40000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- available spare has fallen below threshold
- NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x0d
Temperature:                        46 Celsius
Available Spare:                    0%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    15,350,603 [7.85 TB]
Data Units Written:                 10,703,203 [5.48 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 146,613,844
Host Write Commands:                113,070,930
Controller Busy Time:               264
Power Cycles:                       576
Power On Hours:                     1,886
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   39
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    81,685
Error Information Log Entries:      81,767
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0      81767     9  0x0028  0xc502      -     28293480     1     -
  1      81766     9  0x0023  0xc502      -     28292904     1     -
```

So, do you guys think it could be fixed via CLI or is it fully dead?
(Precision : There is no important data left here, I backed up everything)
Thanks!

Comment: Replace it.....

Comment: Sad :/
I'll wait a little more to see if anyone can help, if not I'll consider replacing it

Comment: @YamiTheNeko, Particularly sad is that it only was turned on 576 times, and was in use for less than 2,000 hours! You might check with Western Digital or the place you bought it; it might be in warranty.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik Yeah, it's not an old laptop, bought it only 6 months ago. I'll try reaching out MSI or WD to get it replaced. Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Comment: I know this is akin to asking if it's plugged in, but have you tried running fsck, and if so, what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the SMART technology in modern drives is to let drives report on statistics and conditions of the drive, such as the number of retries it has to make, the number of sectors that needed to be remapped, and other conditions that indicate the health and predicted availability of the drive.

In this case, your drive is telling you that it's failed for several reasons and has placed itself into read-only mode to protect your data.  At this point, the only thing left to do is replace it.  The damage is likely physical and you won't be able to repair the chips that are in the NVMe that are having problems, since those chips are going to be soldered to the drive and not user replaceable.

Your drive looks like it might be fairly young, and it is known that some technology does fail relatively early on in its life.  So if it's still under warranty, you could try asking for a replacement from the manufacturer.  Otherwise, it's just normal hardware failure, and you can congratulate yourself on having good backups.

Comment: It's only 6 months old, that's why I hoped there was a way to get it out of r-o mode. I bought an equivalent one for the replacement because I need it for work, but I will reach out to MSI and WD to see if I can use my warranty to get a new one. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Even if you could get it out of read-only mode, you probably wouldn't want to trust it with your data.  When the drive says, “Hey, look, I'm broken,” it probably is.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't be safe to put anything here.

Comment: By the way, is it possible that this issue was caused by software or is it only a hardware problem?

Comment: It is almost certainly a hardware problem.  If normal usage can cause a disk to go bad like this, then it's almost certainly a defect in the disk itself.  I would say that it's probably a coincidence.